# Let $M$ be a left $K$-module, then we have that $K \tilde{\otimes} M \cong \tilde{M}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, modules

Let $M$ be a left $K$-module. Let $\tilde{\otimes}$ denote the topological tensor product and $\tilde{M}$ the h-adic completion of $M$. Then we have that $K \tilde{\otimes} M \cong \tilde{M}$. **This means that $K$ serves as a unit for completions.**

I'm having problem understanding what the bold part is saying exactly... I understand the isomorphism $K \tilde{\otimes} M \cong \tilde{M}$ as well as its completely algebraic counterpart $K \otimes_K M \cong M$, but maybe not a good understanding of what it means for something to be a unit in general. To me, a unit just means an invertible element.

Thanks!

Comment: That's right. The point is that tensoring with $\tilde M$ is like multiplying by $1$.

Comment: Tensoring with $\tilde{M}$? You mean $K$? Or $M$?

Comment: Yes sorry I mean $K$ (it's too late to edit)

Comment: Ahh,  i see I think. If we have an algebra $A$ over $K$ then for $k \in K$ the unit $\nu: K \rightarrow A$ is defined by $\nu(k)=k1$.. .... So it's almost like $M$ is our base field for $\tilde{M}$ or something.. I need to think about this more